# How to convert numbers to Date in Android?

Tags: java, android, date-format, date-formatting

Am using webservices to display the data on my screen. One of the fields in the data is DATE. And instead of may 15, it is getting displayed as 1340389800000.
For example, "Meeting at 5:00pm on May 15" is displayed as "Meeting at 5:00pm on 1340389800000" . Not sure what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: DateFormat.getDateFormat(mContext).format(new Date(myTimestamp * 1000))

Answer (score 1):

1340389800000 is probably the unix timestamp ie the number of seconds since 1 jan 1970. You should convert it to date using java.util.Date API :

```
Date yourDate = new Date(1340389800000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a long value containing the milisecs since Jan. 1, 1970 GMT. Try this code:

```
Date d = new Date(yourLongVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

//need to convert  UNIX Timestamp to std formate

```
DateFormat.getDateFormat(mContext).format(new Date(myTimestamp * 1000))
```

//converting to sec need to multiply by 1000

Answer (score 0):

Make a string property in web service for example dateofbirth I am defining here, and return your datetime variable as:(c# code)

```
    public string DateOfBirthString
    {
        get { return DateOfBirth.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); }
        set { DateOfBirth = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) : Convert.ToDateTime(value); }
    }
```

because this will return string so it will be same at client side so and aslo take string dateTime from user and convert it.